# Editing related data in MVC results in error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to adapt [this solution](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to my project.

I have Employees that can have multiple ServiceAreas (many-to-many)
i.e.

```
public class ServiceType
{   public int Id { get; set; }
...
    public virtual ICollection<ServiceSubtype> ServiceSubtypes { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Employee
{ public int Id { get; set; }
...
public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees{ get; set; }
}
```

In the HttpPost of the Edit action for Employee I have added the equivalent of the the following to my project

```
var instructorCourses = new HashSet<int>
(instructorToUpdate.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID));
```

Mine reads like this

```
var employeeServiceTypes = new HashSet<int>
(employee.ServiceTypes.Select(c => c.Id));
```

But right at that point I get the following error:

> Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: source
>
> Line 140:            var employeeServiceTypes = new HashSet
>
> Line 141:                (employee.ServiceTypes.Select(c => c.Id));

I can't figure this one out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah but that's normal behavior. If none have been set... Any clever work-around?

Comment: Do you recommend creating a default ServiceType and applying it to all Employees? That seems like a waste of DB space from a DBA perspective and also then I'd have to mask that useless value!

Comment: I moved my comments with code into a answer. Writing answers into comments is bad practice here :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one employee has `ServiceTypes = null`

You can't access the `Id` in that case `Select(c => c.Id)` - otherwise this exception appears.

You just have to avoid the acces by filtering employees without `ServiceTypes` or avoid the access by a `if` clause.

```
HashSet<int> employeeServiceTypes = new HashSet<int>();
if (employee != null && employee.ServiceTypes != null)
{
    foreach (int id in employee.ServiceTypes.Select(c => c.Id))
    {
        employeeServiceTypes.Add(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: You were completely right. But the ServiceTypes where null because they were not dealt with properly in my HttpPost. I didn't follow the tutorial author's steps to the letter. I'm replaced my old HttpPost with his one and modified it and now the solution is working. Thanks again!